# Proving you can write the Gaussian integers in a certain form

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, gaussian-integers

**Question:** Show that any element of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ can be written in the form $c+x$ where $c\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $x \in I$ where $I$ is the principal ideal $I= \langle 2-i\rangle$ generated by $2-i$

**Answer:**

I am given a hint to observe that $5=(2-i)(2+i) \in I$ but I don't see why I need it.

We have to prove that for any $a,b \in \Bbb Z$

$a+bi=c+x= c + (x+yi)\cdot(2-i)$

Which implies

$a=c+2x+y$

$b=2y-x$

Doesn't this prove that I can write any member of $a+bi$ as a $c+x$?

Comment: Note that proving you can write them in this form is just showing that $$\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2-i\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$$
This is likely what the hint about $5 = (2+i)(2-i)$ is about.

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Are you comfortable with quotient rings?  What I put is more the abstract algebra approach of doing it.

Comment: I am in the process of learning quotient rings. I understand what the equation means. However I don't understand why that is the logical step to take

Comment: The quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2-i\rangle$ has elements of the from $z +\langle 2-i\rangle$.  You want to show that $z \in\lbrace0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$.  This is equivalent to showing that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2-i\rangle$ is isomorphic to the ring on $\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$, which is $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do not delete your question right after somebody answered. That is rather impolite towards the answerer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\rm mod}\,\ i\!-\!2\!:\,\  \color{#c00}{i\equiv 2}\,\Rightarrow\,0\equiv (\color{#c00}{2\!-\!i})(2\!+\!i)=\color{#0a0}{5},\ $ so $\,\ a +\color{#c00}i\,b\,\equiv\, (a+\color{#c00}2\,b) \bmod \color{#0a0}5\,\in\, \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$

Answer (score 0):

Elementary solution: it is clear that every gaussian integer is $\equiv n\mod 2+i$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Further any integer is congruent to $0,1,2,3,4$  modulo $5$, and thus modulo $2+i$.

Conceptual solution: The number of residue classes modulo an algebraic number is $N\alpha$ where $N$ is the norm. Some take this as the definition, in which case it is theorem that this is the product of the conjugates. Thus in this case, residue field has order $N(2+i)=5$ and there is only one such field.

Answer (score 0):

We will prove 
$$
\Bbb{Z}[i]/(2-i) \cong \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}
$$
 First define
$$
\phi: \Bbb{Z} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}[i]/(2-i),\quad\phi(z) = z + (2-i)\Bbb{Z}[i]
$$
Clearly $\phi$ is a homomophism and
$$
\ker \phi = (2-i)\Bbb{Z}[i] \cap \Bbb{Z}
$$
For any $z \in \ker \phi$
$$
z = (2-i)(a+bi)=2a+b+(2b-a)i
$$ 
where $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$. But 
$$
2a+b+(2b-a)i \in \Bbb{Z}\iff 2b-a=0\iff a=2b
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\ker \phi = (2-i)\Bbb{Z}[i] \cap \Bbb{Z} &= \{a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\mid (2-i)(a+bi)\}
\\
&= \{b \in \Bbb{Z}\mid 2\cdot 2b+b +0i \}
\\
&= \{b \in \Bbb{Z}\mid 5b \}
\\
&= 5\Bbb{Z}
\end{align}
Hence 
$$
\Bbb{Z}[i]/(2-i) \cong \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}
$$